# AWS Elastic BeansTalk Django cronjob post request returning 403 error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on a software function in which I have to delete files periodically using **Django + cron + AWS**. The problem is I can't make it work. What's the best way to make it work? Am I missing some AWS configuration? I've configured one **web server** and one **worker** environment, deployed the same application version on them. The task is a **view** mapped into a **url** (accessing the url the function is executed). There's a confirmation message on the worker environment:

> Successfully loaded 1 scheduled tasks from cron.yaml.

But also an 403 error on the worker **access_log**:

> "POST /networks_app/delete_expired_files HTTP/1.1" 403 2629 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.0"

**cron.yaml**:

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "delete_expired_files"
   url: "/networks_app/delete_expired_files"
   schedule: "10 * * * *"
```

url mapping at **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^delete_expired_files', views.delete_expired_files, name='delete_expired_files'),
]
```

function to delete files at **views.py**:

```
def delete_expired_files(request):
    users = DemoUser.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        documents = Document.objects.filter(owner=user.id)
        if documents:
            for doc in documents:
                now = timezone.now()
                if now >= doc.date_published + timedelta(days=doc.owner.group.valid_time):
                    doc.delete()
```

My **IAM** roles are:

> AmazonSQSFullAccess
>
> AmazonS3FullAccess
>
> AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess
>
> AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess

If I access the url via browser, the task is executed (the expired files are deleted). However, the worker environment was supposed to access the url and execute the task automatically and not only when I access the url via browser. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. In my case, I needed to modify 2 things to get it to work:

1. **Ensure the view is set up to accept a POST action from AWS.** Previously I had mine set up as GET only, and it doesn't seem that AWS supports GET cron requests.
2. **Once it supports POST, make it CSRF-exempt, so that Django isn't afraid that there's a CSRF threat taking place when AWS makes POST requests lacking a CSRF token**. You can use the `@csrf_exempt` decorator described at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16458216/4185989); in my case, it was slightly more complicated still by my using a class-based view, and I found this [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17611254/4185989) on how to include the `@csrf_exempt` decorator on a class-based view.